# Can't install Windows on Bootcamp

Tags: bootcamp, usb, install, windows

I have been trying to install Windows for 2 months but I don't know what to do. I start by opening Bootcamp-assistant and choose (translated, not exactly what it is in the English version) "Create an installation disk for Windows 7 or later. Then click continue, and choose my ISO which is directly created from a legit CD in Disk Utility. For USB, I choose my USB.

Then is just says this (again, not exact but translated):

> A bootable USB could not be created
>
> Boot Camp only supports and installation of Windows 7 or later on this platform. Use an ISO file for the installation of Windows 7 or later.

So what's wrong? I have been trying all different formats form my CD.

Comment: There are a few things that could be happening: 1) The ISO is not valid, even if created from the legit disk due to possible copyright protection on the disc. Try downloading the ISO from a known valid source and use your normal key. 2) The ISO could be 32-bit - Bootcamp requires 64-bit versions of Windows

Comment: What size is the USB-Drive? AFAIK it should be greater than 4GB.

Comment: Does your Mac have a optical drive? If not, then how did you make the iso file? If so, then did you try installing using the DVD?